# Error message when attempting to save something to firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I'm tryna upload images to fireabase storage, and also have it added to the Realtime Database with name and storage url. I'll drop the snippet of code I'm having issues with here. What I put stars around  is what I assume is causing me this error message: *Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Pictures.KULT.Link'* (KULT would be ImgName). I'm wondering what specifically did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

````
  ImgName = document.getElementById('namebox').value;
  var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref("Images/"+ImgName+".png").put(files[0]);

  uploadTask.on("state_changed", function(snapshot){
    var progess = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
    document.getElementById('upProgress').innerHTML = "Upload "+progess+"%";
  },
  
  function(error){
    alert("Det oppsto en feil.")
  },

  function() {
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
      ImgUrl = url;
    });

    **firebase.database().ref("Pictures/"+ImgName).set({
      Name: ImgName,
      Link: ImgUrl
    });**

    alert("Bildet er lastet opp.");
  });
}```

really appericiate any help <3
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are only setting `ImgUrl` upon completion of the `getDownloadUrl` function:

```
   uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
      ImgUrl = url;
    });
```

...but that is asynchronous, and so is not going to happen until *after* you make the call below to `set`. The `ImgUrl` variable will be undefined at the time you make the call, hence the error message.

You could fix this, for example, by moving the entire `set` call into the handler for the getDownloadUrl() promise, something like:

```
 function() {
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
      ImgUrl = url;
      firebase.database().ref("Pictures/"+ImgName).set({
        Name: ImgName,
        Link: ImgUrl
      });

      alert("Bildet er lastet opp.");  
    });
  });
```